# Invalid argument - Google map error in Edge browser

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ecmascript-6, microsoft-edge

I have been getting this error

> Invalid argument

from Google map v3 in Edge browser. Everything else is working fine even after getting the error. This strange behavior is occurring only when I try to move the cursor out of the map to the right side (over the browser scroll). It is happening only in Edge.

I have created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abinthaha/gsnyLeuz/) which is in the pristine condition as Google mentioned. But am getting the same error in that case also. I have reported [this bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112324143) to the google map support forum and in the meanwhile trying to find a solution from the largest community I know. Thanks in advance. You can check the code below

```
function initMap() {
  var uluru = {lat: -25.344, lng: 131.036};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
      document.getElementById('map'), {zoom: 4, center: uluru});
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: uluru, map: map});
}
```

Comment: Your fiddle link is dead.

Comment: Hi, please find this link. I think its all same. I mean a simple map can cause the same issue => https://jsfiddle.net/abinthaha/rt7kmh21/

Comment: Your script generates an error which is different than the one you mentioned.

Comment: Did you checked in EDGE?

Comment: No. And I don't have Edge. Your script says `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'icon' of undefined`. When opening a question here, it might be worth checking that your links work and that your scripts don't create errors, others than the one you are describing. Just saying...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/abinthaha/rt7kmh21/521/ - This doesn't have script errors. But when you open this in EDGE and do the above procedure. You will get the error as I asked in the question 'Invalid Argument'

Answer (score 8):

I was able to reproduce the issue and here is what I have found:

The problem occurs in the following code in common.js file on the edge:

```
if ("undefined" != typeof a.compareDocumentPosition)
    return a == b || !!(a.compareDocumentPosition(b) & 16);
```

specifically `compareDocumentPosition` function call as it does not like argument b. The actual function block:

```
function (a, b) {
    if (!a || !b)
        return !1;
    if (a.contains && 1 == b.nodeType)
        return a == b || a.contains(b);
    if ("undefined" != typeof a.compareDocumentPosition)
        return a == b || !!(a.compareDocumentPosition(b) & 16);
    for (; b && a != b;)
        b = b.parentNode;
    return b == a;
};
```

This block is called whenever `mouseout` event occurs on map container and argument a is your map container element and b is scrollbar object. When you move mouse out of the map and onto the scrollbar of the browser window all other browsers call the same method with `nodeType` of scrollbar object being 1 and in turn executing `return a == b || a.contains(b);` code block.

However, in case of edge `nodeType` for scrollbar object is `undefined` and it executes `return a == b || !!(a.compareDocumentPosition(b) & 16);` codeblock and passes scrollbar object to `compareDocumentPosition` function call which then logs **Invalid argument.** on the console.

You can see the bug report that I filed [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/19217918/).

Comment: Thanks for the update. But it's not solved yet and the issue keeps coming up.

Comment: @abinthaha Is it breaking your application? To me those just seems console errors and not the exception so it should not break your app in any possible way.

Comment: Yeah, I mean console errors. But my application is already in the market and users reporting this issue repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Edge ...but calling the map `id="map"` is a common source for issues. see if this works (the console is intentionally being enabled; just ignore the first three errors and the warning logged). in case it works... there should at least no `invalid argument` error follow up.

```js
function initMap() {
  var uluru = {lat: -25.344, lng: 131.036};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {mapTypeId: 'satellite', zoom: 13, center: uluru});
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: uluru, map: map});
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html, body, #map_canvas {height: 100%; width: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```